# Json string more than 524288 exception

Tags: grails, groovy

I try to parse a huge json file, it's more that 524288 characters and I can't parse it with groovy and haven't text of exception. Is it a known issue, is there any workaround?
Can it be limitation of tomcat?

**Update:**
I've got an exception:

```
ERROR (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver) - JSONException occurred when processing request: [POST] /person/parsePersonJson
Expected a ',' or ']' at character 524288 of ...
```

**Update2:**
in grails I used:

```
JSON.parse(params.myJson)
```

Changed tomcat settings of `maxPostSize` to **"0"**

Comment: Validate json payload in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: @dmahapatro, json is valid, when it's less than 524288

Comment: How are you parsing it?

Comment: @tim_yates, I used JSON.parse from grails.converters package. But I also think, that the problem could be specific for groovy

Comment: Still have limitation of the package: 524288, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with input size. Max input size by specification is 512k

Answer (score 0):

It may concern to value of configured POST parameter size in Tomcat (maxPostSize). You should refer to this documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html (keyword: "`maxPostSize`") for more explanation. Then you can try to increase that value. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah, I changed this value to "0", I use tomcat 7. But still have some problems, maybe it's a problem of grails, not tomcat.

Comment: I still have limitation `524288` bytes for json, where can I change it, any ideas?